# Integrate $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}$ from $-1$ to $1$ using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried integrating using the "dog bone", (wich idea is explained fairly well in this post: [Integrating around a dog bone contour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143137/integrating-around-a-dog-bone-contour)). I oriented the curve counter-clockwise.

Integrating along the dog bone (and computing the limit) gives me $-2I$, where $I$ is the integral i have to compute.
Then computing the residues I find that the residues at $i$ and $-i$ are opposite, so they cancel each other out, while the one at infinity equals $-i$.
Using the residue theorem, I find that $-2I=-2i\pi*(-i)$, but that is different from $(\sqrt2 - 1)*\pi$ which is what Wolfram Alpha gives me.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you calculated the residues?

Comment: I calculated the limit, for z approaching the point i or -i, of f(z)*(z-i) or f(z)*(z+i)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think you've asked your question well. You could possibly include a few more details and present it slightly better using more MathJax, but I think your post is otherwise quite good.

Comment: For the one at infinity, I calculated the residue in 0 of $g(z)=-\frac{1}{z^2}*f(\frac{1}{z})$

Comment: Yeah i know, i'm not really good at writing in MathJax

Comment: @Omega Please outline your calculations more. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216820/computing-int-11-frac-sqrt1-x2x21-using-residue-calculus?noredirect=1&lq=1 for a complete proof. Note your residues should not have opposite sign if you are keeping track of branch cuts properly; best to not trust mathematica on this one

Comment: You thus get $$\left(-\tfrac{i\sqrt{2}}{2} -\tfrac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}  \right) \cdot (-2 \pi i) + 2I = -2\pi i \cdot (-i)$$ i.e. that $$2I = 2\pi \sqrt{2} - 2\pi  \implies I = \pi(\sqrt 2 - 1)$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [computing $\int _{-1}^1\:\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2+1}$ using residue calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216820/computing-int-11-frac-sqrt1-x2x21-using-residue-calculus)