# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{1-2a\cos\theta+a^2}\mathrm{d\theta}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Evaluate by complex methods. Please help.

Evaluate $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{1-2a\cos\theta+a^2}\mathrm{d\theta}$$

Comment: Put $e^{i\theta}=z$.

Comment: Recall that $\cos \theta=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$, let $z=e^{i\theta}$, we have $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta=iz d\theta$. Thus $$\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos\theta)d\theta=\oint_{C(0,1)}\frac{f(\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1}))}{iz}dz$$ where $C(0,1)$ is the unit circle. Then apply residue theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos{\theta}}{1-2a\cos{\theta}+a^{2}}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{1-ae^{i\theta}-ae^{-i\theta}+a^{2}}d\theta$$
Let
$$e^{i\theta}=z$$
$$dz=izd\theta$$
then
$$I=\frac{1}{2i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1+z^{2}}{z(z-a)(z-1/a)}dz$$
I'll assume $a\in\mathbb{R}$. The first case $|a|>1$, then there are two poles inside the contour, one at $1/a$ and one at $0$. The residue at $1/a$ is
$$\frac{1+a^{2}}{1-a^{2}}$$
The residue at $0$ is
$$1$$
So,
$$I_{|a|>1}=\pi\Big(1+\frac{1+a^{2}}{1-a^{2}}\Big)=\frac{2\pi}{1-a^{2}}$$
Now, the second case $|a|<1$, there are two poles inside the contour, at $a$ and at $0$. The residue at $0$ is still $1$. The residue at $a$ is
$$\frac{a^{2}+1}{a^{2}-1}$$
Thus
$$I_{|a|<1}=\pi\Big(\frac{a^{2}+1}{a^{2}-1}+1\Big)=\frac{2\pi{a}^{2}}{a^{2}-1}$$
Finally, if $a=1$. If $a=1$ you need to deform your contour, as now you wold have a pole on the contour. For info see [Pole on a contour. Problem with integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110635/pole-on-a-contour-problem-with-integration)