# Different answers on $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{ix}+c}\ dx$ where $c\in\mathbb{C}$ is fixed

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

Upon the substitution $z=e^{ix}$, I get that this is equal to

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{dz}{z(z+c)},$$

where the integral is over the unit circle. I then split this up into

$$\frac{1}{2c\pi i}\left(\oint_{C} \frac{dz}{z}-\oint_{C}\frac{1}{z+c}\right)dz.$$

From here, I get that the first integral is $2\pi i$ and the second integral is $2\pi i$ if $c$ is inside the unit circle and $0$ if $c$ is outside. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110635/pole-on-a-contour-problem-with-integration), it seems as if the second integral should be $\pi i$ if $c$ is on the unit circle itself. Thus, I get that this integral should be

$$f(c)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{ix}+c}\ dx = \begin{cases} 0 & \mathrm{if}\ |c|<1 \\ \frac{1}{2c} & \mathrm{if} \ |c|=1 \\ \frac{1}{c}  & \mathrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

However, upon experimentation with various values of $c$ on [the Online Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), it seems as if

$$f(c)=\begin{cases}0 & \mathrm{if}\ c=0 \\ \frac{3}{2} & \mathrm{if} \ c=1 \\ \frac{1}{c} & \mathrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

What's going on?

Comment: I suspect the calculator is doing much the same as you are, and is just handling the case where the second pole is actually on the integration contour - that is, where the original integral has a pole within the region of integration - poorly.  Note that when $|c|=1$ the integral _doesn't_ have a 'true' value, just a (Cauchy) Principal Value, because it blows up within the range of integration.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks - I suspected that there was something off about the way it was handling PVs, but I couldn't quite put a finger on it. Are my answers correct (including for PVs on $|c|=1$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c=0$, then
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{e^{ix}+c}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ix}dx = 0.
$$
If $c\ne 0$, then
\begin{align}
   \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{e^{ix}+c}&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\frac{1}{ie^{ix}}d(e^{ix})}{e^{ix}+c} \\
  &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z(z+c)} \\
  &=\frac{1}{2\pi ic}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+c}dz.
\end{align}
If $|c| < 1$ the above is $0$. If $c > 1$, the above is $\frac{1}{c}$.

Comment: But the question is specifically asking about a case where $|c|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did I calculate the PVs correctly if $|c|=1$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut : Yes, because you're dealing with half the residue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually when $|c|=1$, as you have correctly observed: the second integral is $\pi i$. Hence, the total integral evaluates to $\frac{1}{2c}$, as is also correctly observed.

This result is confirmed by WolframAlpha: when [$c=1$](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2pi+1%2F%28e%5E%28ix%29%2B1%29+dx) $$:= \frac{1}{2c}\bigg \lvert_{c=1} = \frac{1}{2}$$ and when [$c=-1$](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2pi+1%2F%28e%5E%28ix%29-1%29+dx), the integral does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still have a couple questions: 

1. Is my answer correct everywhere other than $c=1$? and 

2. Why should $c=-1$ be different from any other $c$ on the unit circle? Can't one use the substitution $x\to x+\pi$ to get that $f(1)=-f(-1)$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Note that when $|c|=1$, the above results are the Cauchy Principal values. Yes, for all other values of $c$, the answer is fine. Interestingly, the integral calculator you mentioned gives a value of $-1$ when $c=-1$!!

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. So, is the principal value $\frac{1}{2c}$ for all $c$ on the unit circle, or is $c=-1$ a special case?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut $c=-1$ is a special case, sir..

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the substitution $x\to x+\pi$ give (in a principal-value sense) that $f(1)=-f(-1)$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Sir, the integral calculator mentioned by you gives $-1$ when $c=-1$ m contrasting to WA...

Comment: Yes, and the integral calculator seems to be wrong about most principal values. But why should $c=-1$ be distinct from any other $c$ on the unit circle? I don't understand why it's a special case.