Contour integral with simple pole on contour
I want to compute
$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$ where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius 1 centered at $z=-1-i$, positively oriented.
I know that the integrand has a simple pole at $z=-i$ which is contained on the contour so I instead look at the Cauchy Principal value and take the integral over $C$ where $C $ is formed by deleting a portion of $\gamma$ and creating a small semicircle of radius epsilon centered at $z=-i$ to close the curve and omit $z=-i$ from the interior of the curve, and then letting epsilon go to $0$. I thought that then by Cauchy's theorem, I should have
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\pi i \text{ Res}_{z=-i}\frac{1}{z^2+1} = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$ since integrating over half of the small circle of radius epsilon with negative orientation contributes $-\pi i \text{ Res}_{z=-i}\frac{1}{z^2+1} $. Is that correct? When I check on Mathematica with the following code:
ContourIntegrate[1/(z^2 + 1), Element[z, Circle[{-1, -1}, 1]],
PrincipalValue -> True]
I get no output.
Also, if the above is correct, this method seems to work for any meromorphic function with simple poles which lay on the contour of integration. What happens if the poles are of higher order?
Thanks!

how is $C$ a closed curve? - the points of intersection of the two circles have odd incidence so anyway you go (continuously) on $C$ you must start at one and end at the other so you cannot close it - remember that the residue theorem applies only to closed (rectifiable) curves (or possibly a disjoint union of such)

Sorry, I did not write what I intended. I intended my curve C to be a closed curve which avoids the pole by creating an indentation in $\gamma$ at $z=-I$. I will fix that.

yes but that is what I am saying - if you create an indentation at $i$ which circles it you won't get a closed curve; if you create an indentation that goes only one-half around $i$ to close the cut then the result depends if $i$ is inside or outside the indentation - remember that closed curves cannot have points of odd incidence as if you go in, you must go out too

I want to delete a portion of $\gamma$ and instead include a small semicircle around $i$ which closes the curve so that $i$ is no longer contained in the interior of the curve.

OH I see where the miscommunication is; I keep writing $-i$ and my computer autocorrects it to $I$ which I then change to $i$, not realizing the minus got dropped. I apologize! I want to avoid the pole $-i$.

I understand that but the issue is that you can do that and have $i$ inside or outside depending on which way you go and the result is different in the two cases

Is it OK if I move the discussion to chat? I got the same answer when creating a contour which includes $z=-i$ in the interior since now we will be integrating around the smaller semi-circle in the positive direction. So I had $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=-\pi+\pi/2=-\pi/2$.

I do not participate in chat as I find it not useful - I do not get what you want to achieve - the integral with a pole on is not defined; you can try and go around it, but you can do it in two different ways and get two different results - just look at a very simple example like $1/(z-1)$ over the unit circle where you can write explicit computations; not sure what you need this for, what context you have etc as in some contexts it may make sense to force a value over another

I see, so you are saying that more context is needed? I just found a similar post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110635/pole-on-a-contour-problem-with-integration. I guess what I am trying to figure out is, if I come across an integral like I posted above which is not defined, when should I consider the Cauchy principal value? For example, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{x^3}dx$ diverges but we usually consider the PV. And is the computation above how that would be approached?

I guess that post gives a good explanation of why it may make sense to ignore odd order poles on the contour - the context question remains as what is your interest in this particular problem - if it's an exercise than it depends on the specific convention, if it's to use it somewhere same etc; I always think of indeterminacies as context based (think of conditionally convergent double series - or more generally on indices that are not completely ordered and with a first element or the definition of the logarithmic integral
